# replace a string before the semi colon

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have several files, which begins like this :

```
unit,s_adj,partner,stk_flow,indic,geo\time;aaaa;2222;

time,s_adj,partner,stk_flow,lolo,geo\time;bbb;2222;
```

I want to replace the first occurence before the semi-colon with that new occurence YEAR

The desired output would be:

```
YEAR;aaaa;2222;

YEAR;bbb;2222;
```

I tried with the following command line but it does not seem to do what I want

```
awk -F ";" 'NR==1 {$1=""; print "year"}' input_file
```

Your suggestions are welcomed.

Best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
sed 's/[^;]*/YEAR/' file
```

if you only want the substitution happen on the 1st line:

```
sed '1s/[^;]*/YEAR/' file
```

Comment: So the script would be : anything with a semi-colon and before it and replace it with YEAR. Am I correct?

Comment: @AndyK it will remove from the first not `;` char till the next `;` (exclusive)

Comment: @EdMorton from his awk codes, it seems that he just want to do the change on the 1st line. so I think the sed cmd with address `1s/../../` should work. but you are right on the `+ and *` difference.

Comment: That is an interesting day :) . 

Thank you Kent for your answer and most of all , for your politeness.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
awk '{$1="YEAR"}1' OFS=\; FS=\; input-file
```

Comment: Thank you William for your answer.